# providing Dynamic IP addresses in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am having a Jmeter script which is used to hit two IP addresses/ server names. currently I use two Jmeter instances for hitting the two server names. Is there any way to do this in single Jmeter instance, like parameterization of Server names/IP addresses in HTTP Request Default?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. I never tried before, but it seems the **dynamic values, which you define in request defaults are always re-evaluated**.

So you can define it as a javascript random and two strings depending on random value:

```
${__javaScript((Math.random()<0.5)?'ALMA':'KORTE')}
```

Screenshots of the plan and the results:

[image: Http request defaults with JS function]
[image: HTTP request sampler]
[image: One "ALMA" result]
[image: One "KORTE" result]

Generally its still nicer to put the names into a csv file, and to use CSV config element, and to say, that the CSV has a rollover. Quote from [best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html):

> 16.5 User variables Some test plans need to use different values for different users/threads. For example, you might want to test a
>   sequence that requires a unique login for each user. This is easy to
>   achieve with the facilities provided by JMeter.
>
> For example:
>
> Create a text file containing the user names and passwords, separated
>   by commas. Put this in the same directory as your test plan. Add a CSV
>   DataSet configuration element to the test plan. Name the variables
>   USER and PASS. Replace the login name with ${USER} and the password
>   with ${PASS} on the appropriate samplers The CSV Data Set element will
>   read a new line for each thread.

Comment: Thanks Ant. I find JMeter awesome. I like to share what i know.

Comment: thanks Gábor for your answer, will try and let yoou know the results  :)

Comment: @Gábor Lipták check out my answer, I like to share what I know as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

Although I like Gábor Lipták answer I'm gonna offer the alternative for fun.

Let's say you want to perform your test on both `DEV` and `PROD` environments(imaginary environment). Where `DEV` connects to `host1`, `PROD` connects to `host2` and endpoints being the same `/myserviceendpoint`

So start by adding `User Defined Variables` to your thread group. Let's add two variables :

`ENVIRONMENT` -> `${__P(environment,host1)}` and
`ENDPOINT_PATH` -> `/myserviceendpoint`

Add `Http Request sampler` and inside `Server Name or IP` set it's value to `${ENVIRONMENT}` and other ports etc. change accordingly.

So now your default environment is `DEV`. If you want to change your environment to `PROD` add `BSF Preprocessor` and change the `ENVIRONMENT` variable to `PROD` instance.

`vars.put("ENVIRONMENT", "host2");`

So you can disable/enable this `BSF Post Processor` in your test to toggle between `DEV`/ `PROD`. This is for GUI Mode.

This will come handy when you have big test and you're running jmeter with no GUI mode. This part is cool `${__P(environment,host1)}` this is where if you pass no parameters via command line `DEV` value will be used otherwise you can inject value to overwrite `DEV` environment i.e. (see more [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)):

```
jmeter -n -t yourtest.jmx -l testresults.xml -Jenvironment=host2 //running  `PROD`
jmeter -n -t yourtest.jmx -l testresults.xml //running  `DEV`
```

Here is how that looks like screenshots (test plan) :

[image]

Results (with some added samples just for clarity sake) :

[image]

So you toggle environments or running with no gui and inject via command line. You can also do this for other attributes as well i.e port/endpoint etc.